# Noach with seven mistakes

Tags: yiddish, quotations

There is a pithy Yiddish description for a simple matter that has been massively bungled:

*"Noiach mit zibn greizen"* -- [The two-letter name] Noach (נח) spelled with seven mistakes.

Does anyone know how this can actually be done?

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly (but unsurprisingly), there is a [Wikipedia page](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A0%D7%97_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%A2_%D7%A9%D7%92%D7%99%D7%90%D7%95%D7%AA) about this! They give the spelling **ןאוייעך**, which is how the word would be transcribed into Yiddish based on sound alone.

Comment: Phonetics plus the mistaken final ן.

Comment: They could have used a regular כ at the end (as in Gershon's answer), and made it 8 mistakes. "Noiach mit acht greizin" doesn't sound half as good, though.

Answer (score 6):

**נויאהעכ or ןויאהכ**

The Chof at the end is 2 mistakes - as it is instead of the Ches and if it was a Chaf it should be a Chof Sofit

Comment: The ה and ע are just fillers, no real ignoramus would do that. :)
  But if you're using "end letters" already, you might as well put a Nun Sofit at the beginning.

Comment: -1, it wouldn't make a difference if it were a כ or a ך, because both of them are wrong.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Yes but a כ is a double mistake: mistaken consonant and mistaken form.

Comment: @DoubleAA - But nevertheless one mistake within a single letter.

Comment: @AdamMosheh Well clearly he is following my way of counting. Yours is also an inherently consistent way of counting, but since neither is objectively better, I don't see how you can complain about his choice regarding which to use.