# Does the name Daniel really mean: 'G-d is my judge'?

Tags: names, translation, daniel-book-of

Most people pronounce the Hebrew name דניאל as Dani-el.

Surprisingly enough, when the name Daniel is mentioned in Tanach (in the book of Daniel) it is written with a Tzeirei under the Yud with no vowel under the Aleph.

This would mean that we should be pronouncing it as Dani-yell.

(See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14139/jewish-names-commonly-used-in-a-different-form-than-found-in-tanach) for more discussion about names which are commonly pronounced differently than how they are found in Tanach.)

(It's interesting that in English the name is spelled like Dani-el, but it's pronounced like 'Dan-yl' - emphasizing the 'y')

My understanding is that the meaning of Daniel is 'G-d is my judge'

Is this really correct being that the Tzeirei is not under the Aleph?

Comment: In my experience, it's always best to just pronounce it the way the named one prefers.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I changed the title... The other question certainly doesn't ask this (in any case the whole reference to 'Daniel' wasn't really part of the original question anyway)

Comment: I've reopend after removing the duplicate part of the question.

Comment: @TamirEvan See more about Danel here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danel#Danel_and_the_Book_of_Ezekiel